# Getting text from editText after pressing enter

Tags: java, android, android-edittext

I am trying to create an application with android. I use an EditText and want to get the text from it after the user presses the "enter" key on its keyboard. This is the XML code for the editText:

```
<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/nameTxt"
    android:ems="8"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="45dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView2" />
<ListView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/listView"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="36dp"
    android:layout_above="@+id/btnClr" />
```

In my .Java class I have these relevant rows:

```
ArrayList<String> listItems=new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
```

And that function:

```
public void openAddFriend(View view) {
    String txt;
    final EditText editName;
    editName = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.nameTxt);
    ListView lst;

    lst = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView);


    txt = editName.getText().toString();

    listItems.add(txt);
    adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,listItems);

    lst.setAdapter(adapter);

}
```

My goal is to get the string from the EditText and inserts it into a listView. I've tried using OnKeyListener but it didn't work. Can someone give me a direction to a solution? Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

[use this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.OnEditorActionListener.html)

match the actionid with the appropriate IME_ACTION (this depends on the what ime options you have set on the edittext. [see](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android%3aimeOptions)).